# Working with Interfaces in ASP.NET mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, interface

I am trying to Implement an interface which has getFirstStudent method. My Idea is to make this method available to all the viewmodels which are using my partial view. In this way, I will be solving the problem of passing multiple viewmodels(theoretically not possible) to partial view.

Interface

```
public Interface IMiniView 
{
       string GetFirstStudentId();
}
```

FirstViewmodel:

```
namespace XXX.ViewModel
{
    public class StudentsViewModel: IMiniView 
    {
        public IEnumerable<StudentInfoViewModel> StudentList { get; set; }

        public string GetFirstStudentId()
        {
            return = ???????
        }
    }
}
```

I used to get the first student on my partial view as...

```
@Model.StudentsViewModel.StudentList.ElementAt(0).StudentID
```

Now I would like to access it in the GetFirstStudent method. Note that StudentInfoViewModel has a string named as StudentID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
namespace CivicaEducation.Business.Ces.ViewModel
{
    public class StudentsViewModel: IMiniView 
    {
        public IEnumerable<StudentInfoViewModel> StudentList { get; set; }

        private StudentInfoViewModel FirstStudent 
        {
            get 
            {
                if (StudentList == null || StudentList.Count() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                return StudentList.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        public string GetFirstStudentId()
        {
            return FirstStudent == null : string.Empty ? FirstStudent.Id;
        }

                    // you can add more methods / properties to you interface like this
        public string GetFirstStudentName()
        {
            return FirstStudent == null : string.Empty ? FirstStudent.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi kane thanks for reply.. But compiler doesn't like it saying viewmodel doesnot contain any defition for FirstorDefault or Count

Comment: Add in a reference to the `System.Linq` namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
return StudentList.First().SutdentId;
```